# iterate through url params template in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following url to begin with: http://somedomain.mytestsite.com/?offset=0. I'd like to loop through this url by incrementing offset parameter, let's say by 100 each time. Each time I recieve response I need to check some condition to decide whether I should run next iteration. For example:

```
class SomeSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'somespider'

offset = 0
items = list()

def start_requests(self):
    return [scrapy.Request("http://somedomain.mytestsite.com/?offset="+str(self.offset), callback=self.request_iterator)]

def request_iterator(self, response):
    body = response.body
    #let's say we get json as response data
    data = json.loads(body)
    #check if page still have data to process
    if data["matches"]:
        self.items.extend(data["matches"])
        self.offset += 100
        return self.start_requests()
    else:
        #process collected data in items list
        return self.do_something_with_items()
```

This works, but I can't help feeling something wrong with this code. Maybe I should use some scrapy's `rules`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following things could be improved:

1) dont keep items as spider attribute, you will consume extremely high amount of memory with bigger inputs, **use python generators** instead. When you use generators you can yield items and requests from one spider callback without any trouble.

2) `start_requests` are used at spider startup, there seems to be little need to overwrite them in your code, if you rename your method to parse (default method name executed as callback to start_requests) code will be more readable

```
# we should process at least one item otherwise data["matches"] will be empty.
start_urls = ["http://somedomain.mytestsite.com/?offset="+1]

def parse(self, response):
    body = response.body
    #let's say we get json as response data
    data = json.loads(body)
    #check if page still have data to process
    if data["matches"]:
        for x in data["matches"]:
            yield self.process_your_item(x)
        self.offset += 100
        yield self.next_request()
    else:
        #process collected data in items list
        for x self.do_something_with_items():
            yield x

 def next_request(self):
     return scrapy.Request("http://somedomain.mytestsite.com/?offset="+str(self.offset))
```

probably even better version of your callback would be:

```
def parse(self, response):
    body = response.body
    #let's say we get json as response data
    data = json.loads(body)
    #check if page still have data to process
    if not data["matches"]:
        self.logger.info("processing done")
        return
    for x in data["matches"]:
        yield self.process_your_item(x)
    self.offset += 100
    yield self.next_request()
```

Comment: Thank you! I Edited `start_urls` property so that at least 1 item should be processed + there is no need in `next_request` callback due to we do all stuff in `parse` method.